# PHP strlen() and if statement not working correctly

Tags: php, strlen

I have a PHP form that when loads will get some variables. Not all variables are set. In the code I can see if the Variable has been defined by using strlen() and that seem to be working but when I apply an if statement it doesn't seem to work?
GetSettingValue() is a function to get the value in a file, the item in the file might not exist

the code I have tried is:

```
if (strlen(GetSettingValue("Latitude"))==0);{
logEntry("Lat== 0");
    }
```

Just prior to this statement I print the results of strlen(GetSettingValue("Latitude")) and it displays 0 (this is the expected result) And the logEntry gets processed.

But if I want to not enter the if statement I used:

```
if (strlen(GetSettingValue("Latitude"))!=0);{
logEntry("Lat== 0");
    }
```

and the results of strlen(GetSettingValue("Latitude")) right before the if statement shows 0
But the code will process the logEntry. It seems like the result of strlen() doesn't matter?

Any ideas or a better method?

Comment: You have a semi-colon after your condition, which is basically equivalent to an empty block. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just remove the `;` semicolon after the parenthesis and it'll work absolutely fine.

Correction:

`if (strlen(GetSettingValue("Latitude"))!=0) { logEntry("Lat== 0"); }`